# Laravel - Weird Invalid date time format error when updating post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am making an edit page to edit posts on my website, Each post is inside of a channel. When I try to edit the post without changing the channel it is in. It gives me a weird error stating:

```
Invalid DateTime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'PHP' for column 'channel_id' at row 1
```

But however, When I edit the channel too, It works perfectly fine. What is causing this? I think it has something to do with my form. A post has a channel_id. so that connects it to a channel with that ID. The relations between the two is fine.

This the the piece of form that I think is causing the issue:

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="Kanaal">Kanaal:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <select class="form-control" id="Kanaal" name="channel_id">
       <option selected>{{ $post->channel->channel_name }}</option>
       @foreach($channels as $channel)
       <option value="{{ $channel->id }}" {{ old('channel_id') == $channel->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
       {{ $channel->channel_name }}
       </option>
       @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The method where I store the updated post looks like this:

```
public function updatePost(Request $request, $id)
{

    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->channel_id = $request->channel_id;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->text = $request->text;
    $post->slug = str_slug($request->title);

    $post->save();

    return back()->with('flash', 'Het bericht is bewerkt!');
}
```

It reaches the method just fine. But when I do not edit the channel option tag it gives me that error, While if I do edit it, it works fine.

I don't know if I'm explaining this well, But this is the best I can do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<option selected>{{ $post->channel->channel_name }}</option>` is causing problem as it is by default selected and it does not contain any integer value and in your database `channel_id` is an integer

Comment: I need it to let the user know which channel it is in. And when they want to change it they can do that. How can I accomplish that without an error?

Comment: `<option selected>{{ $post->channel->channel_name }}</option>` should not be present in list as you have all post belonging to posts and for your default option there is no channel id

Comment: Use first option as `<option value="">Select channel</option>` and make it `required` if it is required

Comment: It should be, You can change the channel the post is in. But first, you need to know which one it is in. Then you can select a channel from that list and change it to that with no problem. If u want to change only the text and not the channel you need to be able to do that as well but currently, it gives me that error. For my website it is necessary to show the current channel it is in

Comment: @Feudelcosine148 if you want to show the user default selected channel then it should be something like 

`@foreach($channels as $channel)
       <option value="{{ $channel->id }}"  @if(old('channel_id') || (!empty($post->channel->id) &&  $post->channel->id == $channel->id) echo "selected"  >
       {{ $channel->channel_name }}
       </option>`

Comment: to do that you type this `{{ $post->channel_id == $channel->id ? 'selected' : null }}` in your `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->channel_id = $request->channel_id;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->text = $request->text;
    $post->slug = str_slug($request->title);
```

please try this way instead

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->channel_id = $request->get('channel_id');
$post->title = $request->get('title');
$post->text = $request->get('text');
$post->slug = str_slug($request->get('title'));
```

i hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

`<option selected>{{ $post->channel->channel_name }}</option>` is causing problem as it is by default selected and it does not contain any integer value and in your database `channel_id` is an integer.

If it is a required field then please use `required` attribute in `select` tag and change your first option. To do that change

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="Kanaal">Kanaal:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <select class="form-control" id="Kanaal" name="channel_id">
       <option selected>{{ $post->channel->channel_name }}</option>
       @foreach($channels as $channel)
       <option value="{{ $channel->id }}" {{ old('channel_id') == $channel->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
       {{ $channel->channel_name }}
       </option>
       @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

to

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="Kanaal">Kanaal:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <select class="form-control" id="Kanaal" name="channel_id" required="required">
       <option value="">Select Channel</option>
       @foreach($channels as $channel)
       <option value="{{ $channel->id }}" {{ $post->channel_id == $channel->id ? 'selected' : null }}>
       {{ $channel->channel_name }}
       </option>
       @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if you want to use just some attributes of the request

```
// Return the post object
$post = Post::find($id);

// Do your conversion of title to 'slug'
$request['slug'] = str_slug($request->title);

// Call the update method on the model to update
$post->update($request->only(
    'channel_id'
    'title',
    'text',
    'slug'
));

// Explicit save
$post->save();
```

It sounds like your error is probably coming from somewhere in your form request that is not shown in your example. For example you might have a date input somewhere which is trying to insert into your channel_id column (duplicate `name` attributes on form inputs might be the cause).

Hope this helps!